# Eclipse Kepler JPA errors

Tags: eclipse, jpa, dali

I've installed Eclipse Kepler (Build id: 20130614-0229).
When I try to compile my projects I have tons of JPA related errors.
I'm guessing they come from the Dali Java Persistence Tools plug-in, which I can see in the plug-ins list (version 3.3.1).

My questions are:

1) any idea if there is a well known issue with this version of Eclipse/Dali? I'm not only getting errors in my own code, but also in open source projects that should be correct, for example odata4j-examples:
    Duplicate entity name "Employees" found in the persistence unit. Entity names must be     unique.   Employees.java  /odata4j-examples/src/main/java/org/odata4j/examples/producer/jpa/addressbook   line 10 JPA Problem

2) is there a way to disable JPA errors altogether?
Browsing on the net I found many people pointing to Eclipse > Preferences > Java Persistence, but I don't have any menu called "Java Persistence" or "JPA".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can go to Window -> Preferences -> Validation
Uncheck 'Suspend all validators' if needed
Uncheck JPA validator